# Regular Expression to check alphanumeric with decimals but reject only alphanumeric, alphabet or numeric

Tags: java, regex

Need help in forming regular expression to match text's having pure decimals or alphanumeric decimals but ignoring texts with the only alphanumeric without a decimal or only numeric value or only alphabets.

I tried this `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9.]*[0-9]$` but it is accepting even alphanumeric values.

Below are the test results which I am expecting.

| Text | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Test | false |
| Test1 | false |
| 123 | false |
| 123.12.12 | true |
| Test12.123 | true |

Comment: Like this? `^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)+$` https://regex101.com/r/1p5i7i/1

Comment: If the first dot-separated field can have letters or digits, and the rest should only be digits, you need something like `s.matches("\\p{Alnum}+(?:\\.\\d+)+")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a lookahead to make sure that there is at least a single digit, and repeat matching 1 or more times the dot.

```
^(?=[A-Za-z]*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[A-Za-z]*[0-9])` Assert a digit
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed ranges
- `(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)+` Repeat 1 or more times a dot and again 1 or more of the listed ranges
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8PNSau/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex, `\p{Alnum}+(?:\.\p{Alnum}+)+` which can be explained as follows:

1. `\p{Alnum}` specifies an [alphanumeric character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):`[\p{Alpha}\p{Digit}]`
2. `(?:\.\p{Alnum}+)+` specifies a non-capturing group consisting of a dot followed by one or more alphanumeric characters. The non-capturing group must occur one or more times.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = { "Test", "Test1", "123", "123.12.12", "Test12.123", "123.123Test", "Test123.123Test",
                "Test123.12.12Test" };
        String regex = "\\p{Alnum}+(?:\\.\\p{Alnum}+)+";
        for (String s : arr) {
            System.out.println(s + " => " + (!s.matches(regex) ? "false" : "true"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Test => false
Test1 => false
123 => false
123.12.12 => true
Test12.123 => true
123.123Test => true
Test123.123Test => true
Test123.12.12Test => true
```